# parsing sql statement from readline of json-file with psycopg2 - parsing error of sql statement

Tags: python, json, psycopg2

I've made a script that reads the json-style lines from a document. 
Dozens of lines that looks like this:

> {'ip': 'text', 'type': 'ipv4', 'continent_code': 'EU', 'continent_name': 'Europe', 'country_code': 'CO', 'country_name': 'CO', 'region_code': '82', 'region_name': 'Central', 'city': 'city', 'zip': '8900', 'latitude': text, 'longitude': text}

```
f = open("jsondmp.json","r")
    for i in f:
        #print(f.readlines())
        json= f.readline()
        sql = "Insert Into dbo.jsondmp values (%s)" % json
        cur.execute(sql)
```

But i throws an error at me..

```
syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: Insert Into dbo.jsondmp values ({'ip': '*TEXT*', 'type...
                                        ^
```

I've tried to change the string-argument from `(%s)" % json` to `(?)", (json)`

but it just throws an

> argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got tuple instead

I am missing some basic pythonic theory obviously, but cannot seem to get any further.

I tried to make a test-run, to just make the script print the Insert statements containing the json-string as documented here: [docs for psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters)

```
f = open("jsondmp.json","r")
for i in f:
    #print(f.readlines())
    json= f.readline()
    print("Insert Into dbo.jsondmp values ('%s')" % json)
```

and it gave me this string

> Insert Into dbo.jsondmp values ('{'ip': 'text', 'type': 'ipv4', 'continent_code': 'EU', 'continent_name': 'Europe', 'country_code': 'CO', 'country_name': 'Co', 'region_code': '84', 'region_name': 'Capital Region', 'city': 'text', 'zip': '1050', 'latitude': text, 'longitude': text}
>   ')

which looks quite right..

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
sql = "Insert Into dbo.jsondmp values (%s)"

with open("jsondmp.json","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        cur.execute(sql, (line,))
```

Take a look here for more about passing parameters using psycopg2: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

> Why it is better to open file using the `with keyword`: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python

Comment: I see where you are going - better exception handling gives better bug-solution.. However the input syntax is still faulty: `invalid input syntax for integer: "{'ip': '_TEXT_', 'type': 'ipv4', 'contin....`

It still cannot handle the sql syntax values `('{''ip'': ''_TEXT_'', ...`

Comment: Ah yeah, probably because json special chars, take a look there: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation

Comment: Also, your error message tells you the value is invalid for integer, why? Could you update your question with the whole error and traceback?

Comment: Yes, I wonder why it becomes an integer. It does not give any further error or traceback..

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to understand nor interpret the doc page you linked to, into my code.

Comment: The json string that is in the txt-file is basically a key:value format.
`{'ip': 'text', 'type': 'ipv4', 'continent_code': 'EU', 'continent_name': 'Europe', 'country_code': 'CO', 'country_name': 'CO', 'region_code': '82', 'region_name': 'Central', 'city': 'city', 'zip': '8900', 'latitude': text, 'longitude': text}`

Comment: [postgresql json](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/) gives me an example of how to parse the string that becomes the sql query

Comment: Why are there two `text` not enclosed in quotes? Also, you may try to manually copy the content of your file in a query with pgadmin for example, you would see where the formatting error is (if there is one)